# WPF auto complete box : Selected item Index when searching for repetitive items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF auto complete box filled with  List which have repetitive items.
Now when an item is selected i need to get the index so that i want to identify uniquely which item is selected. I cannot go by text in auto complete box alone because they are repetitive and so that need to go in conjunction with selected index.

Seems simple enough but i have not been able to find a solution for this. I see there is a

```
autocompletebox.selecteditem
```

I have not been able to get anything out of that for scenario mentioned. Please suggest.

Comment: if you are using ICollectionView then you can use CurrentItem property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no index for selected item for auto complete box.

So the solution would be to **manage that in your code logic**.

This is what i did when i faced an issue where i have to select the first available item when the auto complete box displayed multiple products and user wants to search for a product that is available.

The first scenario would be to display the list of all products and let him search and select a product. So here the user would be entering the product name (which might be repetitive in the auto complete box)

So you have a search on the List of all products. But now when searching you first loop through your list and find if you are searching for a product name that occurs multiple times.

```
foreach (var products in ListofAllProducts)
        {

            if (Products.ProductName.ToString() == productname)
            {
                i=i+1;
                tempproducts.Add(products );
            }
        }
```

Now you find the first available item by checking the customer name

```
 foreach (var product in ListofAllProducts)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                if (Product.ProductName== productname)
                {
                    return product;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var product in ListofAllProducts)
                {
                    if (int.Parse(product .CustomerID)==0)
                    {
                        return product ;
                    }
                }

                return tempproducts[0];
            }

        }
        return null;           
    }
```